# how to disable frame layout while view stub in visible?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-framelayout, viewstub

Here i want to disable framelayout while on click of viewstub open. view tub popup from the menu icon and in framlayout i inflected fragments.
( One solution I have is to get all the views and setClickable = false. )

But I am looking for some other solution, like to get focus on the current view so that the other views are set disabled.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.yagneshshinde.thalischedule.menuhome.MainActivity">

<include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

<ViewStub
    android:id="@+id/stub_import"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:inflatedId="@+id/content_import"
    android:layout="@layout/menu_layout"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<ViewStub
    android:id="@+id/calander_import"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:inflatedId="@+id/calander_content_import"
    android:layout="@layout/calendar_dialog_basic"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/frameLayoutLinear"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/frameContainer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:foreground="@drawable/dim_layout">

    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<!-- <include layout="@layout/content_main" />-->


  </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I got answer ` public static void enableDisableView(View view, boolean enabled) {
        //view.setEnabled(enabled);
        view.setClickable(enabled);
        if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
            ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup) view;

            for (int idx = 0; idx < group.getChildCount(); idx++) {
                enableDisableView(group.getChildAt(idx), enabled);
            }
        }
    }`